# Problemas subiendo imagenes mediante formsets de django

Tags: python, django, imagen

Buen día la razón por la que hago esta entrada es porque estoy batallando para cargar imágenes utilizando formsets de django, al crear un nuevo producto dos formas aparecen para cargar dos imágenes más, el problema es que al cargar todos los formularios si se crean en la Base de datos estos registros, pero sin las imágenes que se deben cargar. ¡Gracias por adelantado!

models.py

```
class Etiqueta(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Etiqueta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Etiquetas'
class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    descripcionCorta = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    descripcionDetallada = models.TextField()
    imagenPrincipal = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'imagenesProductos/', null=True, blank=True)
    precioOriginal = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    precioDescuento = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default= None, blank=True)
    cantidad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    especificaciones = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    calificacion = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    fechaCreacion = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    etiqueta = models.ManyToManyField(Etiqueta)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Producto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Productos'
class FotografiaProducto(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fotografia = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'imagenesProductos/', null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def addProducto(request):
    data = {
        'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '2',
        'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
        'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
    }
    FotoProductoFormSet = formset_factory(FotoProductoForm, extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formaFoto = FotoProductoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='fotografia')  
        productoForm = ProductoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset = FotoProductoFormSet(data, request.POST, request.FILES)
        if productoForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            nuevoProducto = productoForm.save(commit=False)
            nuevoProducto.imagenPrincipal = request.FILES['imagenPrincipal']
            nuevoProducto.save()
            post = get_object_or_404(Producto, pk=nuevoProducto.id)
            for form in formset:
                nuevaImagen = form.save(commit=False)
                nuevaImagen.producto = post
                nuevaImagen.save()
            return redirect('productoList')
    else:
        productoForm = ProductoForm()
        formset = FotoProductoFormSet(prefix='fotografia')
    return render(request, 'producto/formularioProducto.html', {'form':productoForm, 'formset':formset})
```

forms.py

```
class ProductoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        fields = [
            'nombre',
            'descripcionCorta', 
            'descripcionDetallada',
            'imagenPrincipal',
            'precioOriginal',
            'precioDescuento',
            'cantidad',
            'especificaciones',
            'categoria',
            'etiqueta'
        ]
        labels = {
            'nombre': 'Nombre',
            'descripcionCorta': 'Descripcion corta', 
            'descripcionDetallada': 'Descripcion detallada',
            'imagenPrincipal': 'Imagen principal',
            'precioOriginal' : 'Precio original',
            'precioDescuento': 'Precio con descuento',
            'cantidad': 'Numero de articulos disponibles',
            'especificaciones': 'Especificaciones',
            'categoria': 'Categoria',
        }
        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(),
            'descripcionCorta': forms.TextInput(), 
            'descripcionDetallada': forms.TextInput(),
            'precioOriginal': forms.NumberInput(),
            'precioDescuento': forms.NumberInput(),
            'cantidad': forms.NumberInput(),
            'especificaciones': forms.TextInput(),
            'categoria': forms.TextInput(),
        }

    #etiqueta = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Etiqueta.objects.all())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["etiqueta"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["etiqueta"].queryset = Etiqueta.objects.all()
class FotoProductoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __name__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__
    class Meta:
        model = FotografiaProducto
        fields = [
            'fotografia',
        ]
        labels = {
            'fotografia' : 'Fotografia Secundaria',
        }
```

formularioProducto.html

```
{% extends 'usuarios/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Registro Reventeando</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        {{form2.as_p}}
        {% for forma in formset %}
            {{forma.as_p}}
        {% endfor %}
        <button>Guardar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```